# Unable to create iCloud-Backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, storage

i wanted to create an icloud backup for my iphone.
after i started i lost my wifi connection because i left my house.
after i came back i found out, that the backup failed.

since then i was not able to create another backup.

in one forum i found the answer, to delete all my previous updates. thats why there is written "last backup: never".

when i start my backup, it starts loading first but then stops again.

[image]

what can i do to make it work again?

does this problem even come from the failed connection?

Comment: Could you try connecting your phone with iTunes and make a backup via cable?

Comment: does this solve my icloud over air problem?

Comment: You could at least try it to rule out it's a complete backup disaster, couldn't you?

Comment: i will do that but i would be happy to find a soulution to the original problem

Comment: iTunes backups are a different entity from iCloud backups. It is probably worth doing one until iCloud syncing is fixed for safety, but it won't fix the iCloud situation.

Comment: I would also like to point out that the screen shots were taken showing that iCloud backup failed via cellular data and in order for iCloud backup to function you need to do it via Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step I would try after doing what you have done already would be to turn off iCloud backups and restart the phone before turning it back on again.

If that doesn't work, I would try to initiate the backup from iTunes using the Back Up Now button. (I'm assuming you were trying from the iPhone) Go to iTunes and select your device the you should see this:
[image]

Comment: which of the two worked?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Settings -> iCloud -> Storage & Backup -> Manage Storage -> Device Name( It will have "This Device" written under it) -> Delete Backup

After this go back to the Storage & Backup page, turn off iCloud Backup and turn it on again and try backing up again with "Back Up Now".

The possible reason for the failed backup earlier is the previous session got corrupt due to the break in the network.